# Is it possible to configure phpstorm's console?

Tags: console, phpstorm

I am using the phpstorm and I find it amazing. But I am used to work on a console and I have some problems.

The displaying of the elements when you run a command (for example ls) is line by line, which is not very comfortable, and a lot of other inconveniences.

Is it possible to configure my console (to see the actual folder in which I am running the commands, how to display more "width-spreadely" the outputs of the commands...) ? Or, are there good plugins to achieve that ?

Comment: Vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5166.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, in fact this seems to allow you configure the terminal (of my mac), but not the console of phpstorm, right ?

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround until better internal terminal is implemented.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, ok thanks but why not simply opening my terminal directly from my mac ?

Comment: You can open a terminal window from the External Tools.